# How to add static view to bottom of screen while in a table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

First thing to note is that I don't use xibs or storyboards, so everything needs to be done programatically.

I have a `UITableView` and I need too add a custom static view to the bottom of the screen when the table view is open (it'll function as a toolbar). I can't add it as a direct subview of the tableview because then it scrolls with the table. Also worth mentioning is that all of this is sitting inside of a `UINavigationController`.

Anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: UINavigationController -> UIViewController -> UITableView & UIView(bottom bar)

Comment: What did you use as your Controller, Did you subclass a UIViewController or did you use a UITableViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `UIToolbar` to the bottom of the screen with `UIBarButtonItems` and add `UITableView` to the top of the view controller with height equal tables view height - toolbar height.

Comment: What would I have to add my subview to in order to put it under the table view?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a implementation subclassing UIViewController and adding  UITableView and UITabBarController to it.

```
@interface RKViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITabBar *tabBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end

@implementation RKViewController

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 500)];
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
        self.tableView.delegate = self;

        self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc1.tabBarItem.title = @"Item 1";
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc2.tabBarItem.title = @"Item 2";

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc2, nil];

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [UITableViewCell new];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```